# Lua loadstring Function fail

Tags: lua

Given this code:

```
local fruit = {}
fruit.name = "Bramley"
loadstring("fruit.pips = '2'")
fruit.skinc = 'Red'
print(fruit)
```

Why aren't the pips added to the table:
table

```
'fruit'{
  'name'='Bramley',
  'skinc'='Red'
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[`loadstring()`](https://devdocs.io/lua~5.3/index#pdf-load) (or [`load()`](https://devdocs.io/lua~5.1/index#pdf-loadstring) in Lua 5.2 or higher) returns a function, you have to run that function to execute the code. Like this:

```
fruit = {}
fruit.name = "Bramley"
loadstring("fruit.pips = '2'")()
```

Note that `fruit` has to be global, or an error would be generated because the environment of the returned function of `loadstring` is the global environment.

Comment: Thank you very much! I had tried the additional () the error in my ways was that fruit was a local variable. Thank you very muich for the succinct, forensic answer - knowing my error without me displaying it!